# Question about showing the harmonic series is divergent.

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to show that the harmonic series is divergent by showing that the sequence of partial sums is a monotone increasing sequence that is unbounded?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yes, and that's the standard proof.

Comment: Not only it is possible to do it this way: *Any* proof of its divergence establishes this fact.

Comment: There are rigorous proofs that do not proceed in that way, but they are less informative than partial sum estimates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you have seen the proof by the integral test, and you would like a more "hands on" proof, where you get a bound you can feel.  Here is such a proof:

$$
\begin{align}1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}...+\frac{1}{2^{n}-1} &> \frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}\right) ...+\frac{1}{2^n}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{2}\\
&=\frac{n}{2}
\end{align}
$$

So the sum of the first $2^n-1$ terms of the harmonic series is greater than $\frac{n}{2}$.  Since all the terms are positive, the sequence of partial sums is monotone increasing, and this special subsequence diverges to positive infinity, so we are done!

Comment: That proof is due to Oresme. It's about the only important piece of mathematics to come out of the Medieval ages. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Comparison_test

Answer (score 0):

Another way,
which is moderately equivalent.

Let
$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k}$.
$S_n$ is obviously an increasing sequence.

$S_{2n}-S_n
=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac1{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k}
=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac1{k}
>\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac1{2n}
=\frac{n}{2n}
=\frac12
$

so, by induction
$S_{2^mn}-S_n
>\frac{m}{2}
$
so $S_{2^mn}$ can be made
as large as you want
by making $m$ large enough.

Note that this also shows that
$S_{2n}-S_n
=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac1{k}
<\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac1{n}
=\frac{n}{n}
=1
$
so, by induction
$S_{2^mn}-S_n
<m
$
so to make $S_{2^mn}$
large,
you have to  go up exponentially.

This is why $S_n$ is about
$\log n$.